# How does r calculate the standard deviation and variance for non numeric data?

Tags: r, statistics, standard-deviation, variance

My task was to calculate the standard deviation and variance for four variables from a survey. Two of the variables are numerical but the other two aren't. I ran the following code:

```
sapply(vclms[1:4], var)
```

Vclms is the dataframe that the variables are included in and columns 1 to 4 include all the aforementioned variables (both numerical and otherwise). I expected it to deliver an error for the variance of the non-numerical variables, but instead got the following:

```
> sapply(vclms[1:4], var)
     grosswk        spend     hhldsize          sex 
8.383855e+04 4.744934e+04 1.288881e+00 2.434469e-01 
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is deprecated and will become an error.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is deprecated and will become an error.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
```

I have no idea whether you can consider the answers to the two non-numeric variables (hhldsize and sex) correct or not, but I wanted to know how it could even come up with an answer?

Comment: The deprecation warning is clear: your data has `factor`s, which internally are stored as `integer`s. If your data were actual `character` in those columns, you would instead see `Warning in var(x$x) : NAs introduced by coercion` and a variance of `NA`.

Comment: And you are correct, numerical analyses on the integers of `factor`s are very likely not meaningful. (They *might* be meaningful IFF the underlying data is ordinal and properly ordered.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the warning message indicates this is something that should be avoided, but if you have a factor

```
x<-factor(c("a","b","c","c","d","b","a","b","a","a"))
```

each value in that factor is represented by an integer.

```
as.numeric(x)
# [1] 1 2 3 3 4 2 1 2 1 1
```

The numbers are determined by the `levels()` of a factor. Each level is assigned an integer starting at 1.

```
levels(x)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

So `a=1`, `b=2`, etc

When you do `var(x)`, you are really doing `var(as.numeric(x))`. Note that those numeric values may not be meaningful for your actual data.

```
var(x)
# [1] 1.111111  (plus warning)
var(as.numeric(x))
# [1] 1.111111
var(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1))
# [1] 1.111111
```